# "Table ххх.ууу dosen't exist", при этом она отображается в списке таблиц

Tags: mysql, консоль

База была перенесена со стационара (5.7.10, win7), где всё прекрасно работает, на ноут (5.7.11, win10). Скриншот с тем, как это выглядит прилагается. 
Базу я переносил простым копированием папки с БД в папку /data, если это имеет значение.
[image: Как это выглядит в консоли]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А эта таблица не InnoDB?

Comment: покажите результат `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`

Comment: @tutankhamun Прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: Вы ошиблись. Нужно `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` а не просто `CREATE TABLE users`

Comment: Без разницы, ошибка та же самая.

Comment: Ясно. В общем проблема в том, что переносом файлов нехорошо переносить базу. Скорее всего вы не перенесли хранилище InnoDB. Сделайте дамп базы и импортируйте ее в новом месте.

Comment: Можно немного подробнее, если не сложно? Дамп есть, но не имею ни малейшего понятия как его импортировать через консоль.

Comment: `mysql < dump-file.sql` Добавить ключи `-u` и `-p` при необходимости

Comment: Или еще пара вариантов (непосредственно из консоли) `source dump-file.sql` и `\. dump-file.sql`. Вместо dump-file.sql подставляете имя вашего дампа.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Такая ситуация часто возникает, когда вы переносите frm-файлы таблиц вручную, при этом данные таблиц остаются в табличном пространстве InnoDB. Лучше не переносить базы данных путем копирования файлов. Хотя таблицы MyISAM это допускают, но в этот момент сервер должен быть либо остановлен, либо таблицы заблокированы (например, утилитой `mysqlhotcopy`).

Самым надежным способом переноса базы данных является создание SQL-дампа

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname > dbname.sql
```

с последующим его развертыванием на целевом сервере

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < dbname.sql
```

Здесь root - имя MySQL-пользователя, dbname - имя базы данных, dbname.sql - название файла SQL-дампа